# Child div is not getting the original height of parent div, why?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a trouble with css.

It's been a really long time since I've used css, but now I'm struggling at something really easy, you might say.

Well, the thing is that I created a div with height 1100px and inside the div I have two more divs, while one of them is at the top and the other one is right below the upper div.
The upper div doesn't have height specified, but only uses padding to get height. And the lower div has height set to 100%, so it (basically) should get the height thats left in the parent div, shouldnt it?

At this time, the lower div is overlapping the parent div.

This is my code:

```css
  html, body {
     background: #121212;
     color: #ffffff;
     font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }
    
    * {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
    }
    
    #container {
     margin: 5% auto;
     width: 1100px;
     height: 600px;
     background: #ff9900;
    }
    #container .inner-box-head {
     font-style: italic;
     padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    }
    #container .inner-box {
     height: 100%;
    }
    #container .inner-box .inner-box-video {
     width: 70%;
     height: 100%;
     background: #fff;
    }
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="cs">
     <head>
      <title>jadvo.cz</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
     </head>
     
     <body>
      <div id="container">
       <div class="inner-box-head">
       Diváků: 0
       </div>
       
       <div class="inner-box">
        <div class="inner-box-video">
         <!--<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7JJfJgyHYwU?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>-->
        </div>
        
        <div class="inner-box-chat">
        
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

[Here you can see the result I'm getting...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQadY.png)

Comment: why will it not overlap ? a 600px container cannot have children of more than 600px height, the overflowing children will obviously come out of parent div.

Comment: height 100% would be 100% of the parent's height so no it shouldn't get the rest of the height

Answer (score 0):

> And the lower div has height set to 100%, so it (basically) should get the height thats left in the parent div, shouldnt it?

No. It should have the same height as the parent. 100% means 100% of the height of the parent, not 100% of the height of the parent that isn't used by something else.

> At this time, the lower div is overlapping the parent div.

It doesn't really. The 100% height div is too big to fit inside its parent, so it is sticking out of the parent, and thus impacting into the space below.

---

If you want to have elements which use up the remaining space: Use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to do your layout.

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  max-width: 100px;
}

section header {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: #faa;
  padding: 1ex;
}

section div {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: #aaf;
  padding: 1ex;
}

section footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: #afa;
  padding: 1ex;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <header>Header</header>
  <div>Content</div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</section>

<section>
  <header>Header</header>
  <div>Content</div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</section>

<section>
  <header>Header</header>
  <div>Content</div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</section>

<section>
  <header>Header</header>
  <div>Content</div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You most use `calc()` to because the `.inner-box-head` height Influence on parent div

```css
html, body {
    background: #121212;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    margin: 5% auto;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 600px;
    background: #ff9900;
}
#container .inner-box-head {
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
#container .inner-box {
    height: calc(100% - 32px)
}
#container .inner-box .inner-box-video {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">
    <head>
        <title>jadvo.cz</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="inner-box-head">
            Diváků: 0
            </div>

            <div class="inner-box">
                <div class="inner-box-video">
                    <!--<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7JJfJgyHYwU?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>-->
                </div>

                <div class="inner-box-chat">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Update your last CSS block as this:

```
#container .inner-box .inner-box-video {
    width: 70%;
    height: calc(100% - 10px);  //5+5 padding of top div
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: When someone downvotes an answer they should have courtesy to give apt reason. Unless it is an amateur developer.